# Passing through a parameter in a link without making it visible in the URL

Tags: php

I have a table containing editing links. In the `href` of the links I am passing a parameter to edit a record, but that parameter passed by $ _GET, is seen in the url, and I do not want that variable to be in the url. Is there any way to pass this value through without it being sent in the URL?

```
<td>
  <a class="edit btn btn-default btn-sm" href="newsEdi.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id'];?> ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
  </a>
</td>
<td>
  <a class="edit btn btn-default btn-sm" href="newsEli.php?id=<?php echo  $fila['id'];?> ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: I'd argue that unless that parameter has private information that should not be disclosed, then using the GET parameters like what you're doing there is the *correct* way. An alternate way would be to submit a hidden form as a POST with the action set to the PHP script and a hidden field for the ID.

Comment: My friend there are two ways to hit the server
1. GET
2. POST
If you want to interct with server secrelty you can use POST otherwise get is the option that use URL to send the data on server as your question suggsted. If you willing to hide the url data i will strongly suggest to send encrypted data through your url

Comment: Dymos, How to create a hidden form ?, for example in my case, a button goes to a page called newsEdi.php and there the user is going to edit his information, please an example of your solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to data without exposing them as part of the URL, they need to be in the POST body. Even then, its not guaranteed that a user (or someone in the middle) cannot read the data.

Another alternative would be to obfuscate the id using symmetric encryption like [AES-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), so even if the user can see it, they cannot make sense of it.

Comment: Not quite true, when using HTTPS everything except the URL address portion is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS, everything except the URL address portion is encrypted. Note however that the entire URL will probably end up in the server logs. If you also want to avoid the server logging send sensitive data as a POST, not a GET.